# DirectoryInfo usage in a UWP project

Tags: c#, .net, io, uwp

I am currently working to a Windows 10 UWP project and I keep getting the following exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.IO.FileSystemInfo[]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.IO.FileInfo]'.

and this is the code which throws it:

```
 DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
 FileInfo[] files = dirInfo.GetFiles(path);
```

path is a valid one, i verified it several times, I do not know why I am getting this exception. Can the DirectoryInfo class still be used in a UWP application or should I use an equivalent one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`DirectoryInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt185496.aspx) class is applicable for UWP. However, it has a lot of limitations. Such as whether the path is valid. For more detail you could refer to [Skip the path: stick to the StorageFile](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2012/12/04/skip-the-path-stick-to-the-storagefile/).

It throw `Second path fragment must not be a drive or UNC name` exception when I passed `path` parameter. I found the following description.

> The search string to match against the names of files. This parameter can contain
>    a combination of valid literal path and wildcard (* and ?) characters (see Remarks),
>    but doesn't support regular expressions. The default pattern is "*", which returns
>    all files.

So I modify the `searchPattern` like the following, it works well.

```
string root = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path;
string path = root + @"\Assets\Media";

DirectoryInfo dirinfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
FileInfo[] files = dirinfo.GetFiles("head.*");
```

> I do not know why I am getting this exception. Can the DirectoryInfo class still be used in a UWP application or should I use an equivalent one ?

The best practice to query files in UWP is to use folder picker to select a folder and enumerate all the files with `GetFilesAsync` method. For example:

```
var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker();
picker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
picker.ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
var folder = await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
if(folder != null)
{
    StringBuilder outputText =  new StringBuilder();
    var query = folder.CreateFileQuery();
    var files = await query.GetFilesAsync();
    foreach (StorageFile file in files)
    {
        outputText.Append(file.Name + "\n");
    }
}
```